# Bank statement sync process failed - odoo enterprise v10

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-enterprise

In odoo v10 Enterprise while trying to sync bank accounts for auto feed entries then getting following error.

Once your bank accounts are registered, you will be able to access your statements from the Accounting Dashboard. The available methods for synchronization are as follows.

- Direct connection to your bank
- Importing your statements in via a supported file format (QIF, OFX,
  CODA or CSV format)
- Manually enter your transactions using our fast recording interface

I would like to go with first one **"Direct connection to your bank"**
In that I am facing issue so I want to fix it.

**Issue :**

> **Problem Updating Account(507):We're sorry, Yodlee has just started providing data updates for this site, and it may take a few days to be
>   successful as we get started. Please try again later.**

Comment: I don't see any question here.

Comment: Please review updated questions.

Comment: I am afraid that you will have to ask Yodlee what the error (507) means. They are offering this service and I have no chance to figure out what might be the cause of the problem.